# Local static variable scope in C

Tags: c

I have a simple question about static variables. If I declared a static variable in a function:

```
void main()
{
    int k = 0
    while(k<=4)
    {
        fun();
        k++;
    }
}
int fun()
{
    static int i=5;
    i++;
    printf(Value %d\t", i);
    return 0;
}
```

As I know, the function will deallocate after returning. But where is the `i` value stored. Is a static variable like a global variable.

Comment: `Is static is like global variable.` No!!!! it's same in terms of life time.different in terms of visibility.

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors first and then go to the philosophical questions :)

Comment: The C specification doesn't say where variables have to be stored, just that a local static variables lifetime is over the whole program. However, compilers usually store local static variables together with global variables.

Comment: Also that code has an endless loop, please work on those things first

Comment: 'Tis curious that you have `void main()` which is non-standard and only valid on Microsoft Windows with a Microsoft C compiler, and you have `int fun()` and don't use its return value.  It would be more orthodox to have `int main(void)` and `void fun(void)` — though you'd have to define or declare `fun()` before `main()` if you changed its signature (though C89 compilers such as MSVC don't mind about the implicit `int` rule for functions, but that's a 25-year old standard and the 15-year old C99 standard outlawed implicit declarations for functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function will not deallocate `i` inside `fun()` on return.  The storage for `i` is in the same general area as global variables — but it is not a global variable.  It is only accessible inside the function `fun()` where it is defined. It is separate from any global variable `i` or any other variable `i` that is static inside any other function (in any source file), or from a file scope static variable `i` in the source file where `fun()` is defined.  It has a lifetime as long as the program.

Answer (score 1):

*As I know, the function will deallocate after returning* — **No**. I think your assumption is wrong!

`static` variables won't be deallocated after returning from the function.

**Where is it stored?** — `static` variables are stored in "Data Section" or "Data Memory".

**Life** — The life of the `static` variable starts when the program is loaded into RAM, and ends when the program execution finishes!